# how can i fix concurrently issue running multiple scripts

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have client and server in a separate folder. I think there is an error in client Script. can anyone help me out with the solution. I want to run both client and server simultaneously. Thanks

my folder structure

```
 ----client
 ----server
```

package.json inside server folder

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    **"client": "npm start --prefix client",**
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  }
```

Comment: Do you have separate package.json files for the server and client?

Comment: yea separate package.json files in server and client folder

Answer (score 0):

As you have separate package.json files for the server and client, please try this solution

package.json inside the server folder

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    **"client": "npm start --prefix client",**
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"cd ./../client && npm run client\""
  }
```

Also you can try this one

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    **"client": "npm start --prefix client",**
    "dev": "npm run server & (cd ./../client && npm run client)"
  }
```